# What lower bounds are known on growth of the distribution of the abundancy index?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, multiplicative-number-theory

Let $a(n)=\sigma(n)/n$ be the [abundancy index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number) of $n$ and let $F(x)$ be the distribution function of this index: i.e., the proportion of integers $n$ with $a(n)\leq x$. (This function is well-defined and continuous for the abundancy index, though that's non-trivial). [Erdős proved](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1974-19.pdf) an upper bound of the form $F(x+\frac1t)-F(x)<C/\log(t)$ and showed that this is best possible, and also proved that $F(1+\frac1t)-F(1) \in (1+o(1))e^{-\gamma}(\log t)^{-1}$, but I'm interested in the values of $F(x+\frac1t)-F(x)$ for larger $x$, and interested in inequalities the other direction: is anything known about *lower* bounds for $F()$ in this more general case?

([Asked a week ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681012/lower-bounds-on-growth-of-the-abundancy-index-distribution) on math.se with no answer)

Comment: Does Theorem 1 of this paper http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/aa121-4-6 answer your question? As far as I can tell nothing much more is known, but Paul Pollack has recent works on this topic and would maybe know if there is.